# Need help with depixel in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python3

I'm trying to use a program called "depixel" in Ubuntu 14.04 which seems to be written in python3. I'm trying to use it so I can smooth out a pixel art image I made. [Here](https://github.com/jerith/depixel) is a link to the program. I have the image with the alpha channel removed, but how do I install and run this program?

(If you've never heard of this, you can read about it [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kramnath/edgefoci/paper/pixel.pdf).)

Edit: I got the program set up and left it processing an image for about a day now, it seems to just hang up on me.

Comment: I guess that you just have to run `setup.py` and then > "There is a handy script to depixel PNGs in the `depixel/scripts` directory, and
there are unit tests covering some of the code."

Comment: @dadexix86 when I run setup.py it says no module called "setuptools".

Comment: You should install the dependencies listed in the README file, obviously :) It is a super-alpha stage, so I believe that the author might want to hear from you about your problems :) Or maybe not, since it is not developed since 2012...

Comment: @dadexix86 Yeah I think I got it working but it seems to be taking a while to convert my sprite.

Comment: Great! :D You should write an answer explaining the steps that you used and accept it, so that other in future can refer to it

Comment: @dadexix86 I haven't gotten my image results yet, so it might be a good idea to wait and see if it actually works because the program seemed to hang up on me. It doesn't say the progress unless you cancel it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32563/discussion-between-user245115-and-dadexix86).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1.Download depixel

2.Extract it to a directory

3.Use a terminal to enter it (it should be called "depixel-master"

4.Run the command "python setup.py" as root.

5.Go into "depixel/scripts"

6.Make sure the image you want to use has it's alpha layer removed (You can remove this using GIMP.)

7.Run the command "python depixel_png.py" with the path of your image at the end.

8.Be patient, it might take awhile.